# How do you exclude values with "potential issues" from a Wikidata query

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I am querying for companies to see what other organizations they own. Some of the returned items have "potential issues" that show up on the Wikidata page for the parent company. How do I exclude those?

My query:

```
SELECT ?org ?orgLabel WHERE {
  wd:Q333718 p:P1830 ?relationship.
  ?relationship ps:P1830 ?org.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
ORDER BY ?orgLabel
LIMIT 200
```

Query: https://w.wiki/5WBd

Company page with issues on "Owned by" entries: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q333718

[image: potential issues]

Comment: I don't think that the violation of those constrained is contained in the data directly (at least not in the Wikidata main triple store or named graph) but simply analysed on rendering the web page. That said, for each constraint on each property you'd have to apply a different query pattern - this would definitely need some huge SPARQL query and some time to write a patter for each constraint type